# Is there a way to log Windows command line operations?

Tags: windows, command-line, logging, malware

I have tried looking for an answer to this with no avail. I was just wondering if there was any sort of tool or software that recorded all operations that had been done through command line on a Windows (XP or otherwise) system. I want to be able to track any sort of operations an identified malware executable does through command line.

Comment: Not unless you install DOSKEY or something similar, and then it has to be in the environment path, which your suspected malware would have to use.

Comment: @RandolphWest It could be possible that it DOSKEY is exactly what I am looking for. I will get back at you if that works!